# How can I prevent new iCal events from being all-day by default?

Tags: macos, ical

Up until Lion, I could double-click inside a particular date (in Month view) and it would automatically create a new event whose time that day defaulted to one hour.  I could then change the starting time, and the ending time would automatically adjust to be one hour later.  This was often good enough, and made adding an event very straightforward.

In Lion, the same action produces an *all day* event, which I then have to bring up in the Inspector, switch off **All Day**, and edit *both* the starting and ending times.  It's a good deal more work.  I don't see a Preference for this.  Does anyone know how to restore the pre-Lion behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use iCal's new 'plain English" approach to specify a starting time.

Double-click to create the new event, and include "at 6pm" or whatever when you type in the description. When you hit Return, your event will show the required starting time and will default to a duration of one hour.

Comment: Thanks - that works for me.  When on the phone I have often typed the time into the description, because it required less attention than using the interface; later I've had to come back and fix it.  This is a good feature.